# Prevent nested TeeChart from receiving mouse events at design time

Tags: components, delphi-xe5, teechart, design-time

I made a following simple component with a nested TeeChart. There nothing more in it.

```
unit ExperimentalChart;

interface

uses System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, VclTee.TeeGDIPlus, VCLTee.TeEngine,
  VCLTee.TeeProcs, VCLTee.Chart;

type
  TExperimentalChart = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FChart: TChart;
  protected
    procedure CreateHandle(); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  published
  end;

procedure Register();

implementation

uses System.SysUtils;

procedure Register();
begin
  System.Classes.RegisterComponents('Experimental', [TExperimentalChart]);
end;

constructor TExperimentalChart.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FChart := TChart.Create(nil);
  FChart.ClearChart();
  FChart.View3D := False;
end;

procedure TExperimentalChart.CreateHandle();
begin
  inherited;
  FChart.Parent := Self;
  FChart.Align := alClient;
end;

destructor TExperimentalChart.Destroy();
begin
  FreeAndNil(FChart);
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

When I am using this component at design time and want to move the component on the form, TChart receives all the mouse events and an error box appears:

> Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window.

Stack trace:

```
main thread ($4b54):
50589ae6 +06e vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Forms       5675   +6 TCustomForm.SetActiveControl
50589bef +053 vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Forms       5716   +8 TCustomForm.FocusControl
5046a506 +012 vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Controls   12066   +3 TWinControl.SetFocus
42242810 +074 Tee9190.bpl  Vcltee                    Teeprocs.TCustomTeePanel.MouseDown
422a1be9 +025 Tee9190.bpl  Vcltee                    Chart.TCustomChart.MouseDown
5046318c +08c vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Controls    7363   +7 TControl.DoMouseDown
504631db +03f vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Controls    7374   +7 TControl.WMLButtonDown
50462b49 +2bd vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Controls    7224  +91 TControl.WndProc
50467669 +5c5 vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Controls   10039 +153 TWinControl.WndProc
422423a4 +00c Tee9190.bpl  Vcltee                    Teeprocs.TCustomTeePanel.WndProc
50466cac +02c vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Controls    9751   +3 TWinControl.MainWndProc
501749c4 +00c rtl190.bpl   System.Classes 17010   +5 StdWndProc
75bb3ebb +00b USER32.dll                             DispatchMessageW
50590dc3 +0f3 vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Forms      10288  +23 TApplication.ProcessMessage
50590e06 +00a vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Forms      10318   +1 TApplication.HandleMessage
50591141 +0c9 vcl190.bpl   Vcl.Forms      10456  +26 TApplication.Run
75916357 +017 KERNEL32.DLL                           BaseThreadInitThunk
```

How to inhibit passing events to the chart and allow moving the component at design time?

Comment: I would move the code of CreateHandle to the constructor. In the construction, I would use `FChart := TChart.Create(self);` and completely remove the destructor.

Comment: @fpiette: Thank you. Setting the owner was sufficient. What about the code in `CreateHandle` - this is intentionally so, because of bug in `TChart`. But how to block mouse events? Chart gets zoomed and panned at design-time.

Comment: OK for CreateHandle. For mouse, that looks another bug in TChat. I suggest an interposer class to catch mouse messages.